# g++ 4.6 malloc pointer error

Tags: macos, gcc, malloc

I have just compiled and installed gcc 4.6.0 on my Mac running OSX 10.6 . I have graphite enabled, so i compiled it like this:

`../gcc-4.6.1/configure --with-ppl=/usr/ppl --with-cloog=/usr/cloog  --prefix=/usr/local/ --enable-languages=c,c++`

It build fine and even compiles, but even if I try to execute a program using some libraries like Boost and ROOT I get an error like this:

```
inten(12480) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fff70012500: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap
```

Comment: Maybe a 32/64-bit issue? Did you disable multilibs?

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint on ```malloc_error_break```, in the debugger?

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely a bug in your code. For example, calling `free` twice will cause exactly this. Can you post the smallest piece of compilable code that produces this error?